# How to use Expression.Constant(object value, Type type)?

Tags: c#, expression

I have a problem with using the `ConstantExpression` class:

```
Expression exp = Expression.Constant("1", typeof(Int32));
```

When executing the code from above, the following error is thrown.

> Parameter type mismatch

How can I use the `Constant(object value, Type type)` method?

Comment: `"1"` is not an integer. Use `1` instead.

Comment: You should change `"1"` to `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have passed a [string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string) which says `1`, instead just use the number without the double quotes:

```
Expression exp = Expression.Constant(1, typeof(Int32));
```